# get value of selected <select> element in dart

Tags: dart, select

how i can obtain selected option of  element?
document.query("#id") - returns Element which hasn't value propery
so i can't do:

```
var val = document.query("#id").value;
```

```
var val = (SelectElement)(document.query("#id")).value; // - "SelectElement is class and cannot be used as an expression"
```

how to do type conversion in dart correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need:

```
String str = document.query("#idOfSelect").value;
```

will be warning, but you can ignore it

Comment: It works but I am getting warning and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

In general, when dealing with any HTML element, I usually query the HTML element first:

```
InputElement myElement = document.query(#myInputElement);
```

Then use some event to capture the value contained in that element:

```
int val = Math.parseInt(myElement.value);
```

So for example, in HTML I could have an input element of type range:

```
<input id="mySlider" type="range" min="1000" max="10000" step="20" value="5000" />
```

In Dart, I would grab the value of this slider using a mouse up event:

```
InputElement mySlider = document.query('#mySlider');
mySlider.on.mouseUp.add((e) {
  int _val = Math.parseInt(mySlider.value);
  document.query('#status').innerHTML = "$_val";
});
```

**Edit:** In [M1](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/m1-language-changes/#the-as-cast-operator), you can now just use the cast operator `as`.  If your HTML looked like this:

```
<p id="text">This is some text</p>
```

You could retrieve the text from the paragraph tag by doing this:

```
String str = (query('#text') as ParagraphElement).text;
```

Comment: yes it works, but it is cumbersome variant. in "InputElement mySlider = document.query('#mySlider');" happens type conversion, but i want to do it as in java "(Class)var". is it possible in dart or there is another way?

Comment: Dart is optionally typed, so I don't believe you can do type conversion the way you suggest.  You might want to look at Eli Brandt's article [(Why Dart Types)](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/why-dart-types/) or Gilad Bracha's [(Optional Types)](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/) regarding Dart's type system (ie, it is more like JavaScript's dynamic typing than Java's static typing).

Comment: I like the (query("#text") as InputElement).value syntax. That way you can use typing and contextual method completion like you would in Java. Of course, on the other hand, if you know for sure it's an InputElement, the cast doesn't really do anything except make your IDE happy ...

Answer (score 0):

I used:

`var val = int.parse(query("#id").value, onError: (_) => 1);`

This prevents an exception in case query("#id").value is null and assigns a default value (1).