# How to get a clicked element's text content, with Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm using dart to develop an app and i want to get the value of a clicked element. I.e:

Html:

```
<div id="blah">Value!!</div>
```

Dart:

```
void main(){
    query("#blah").onClick.listen(showValue);
}

void showValue(Event e){
   //Get #blah's innerHtml based on the Event(Something like e.target.innerHtml or e.target.value)
}
```

Anyone? I know how to do it in JS, but I want to know if there's a way to do it in DART!

**Edit**

Thanks to all of you, I'll try to be a little bit more clear. I have a loop that generates 9 elements dynamically and add them to a container.

Code:

```
var j = 0;
  var optionsSquare = query("#optionsPanel");
    while(j < 9){
      DivElement minorSquare = new DivElement();

      var minorSquareHeight = optionsSquare.clientHeight/3;
      var minorSquareWidth = optionsSquare.clientWidth/3;

      minorSquare
       ..attributes = {"class": "miniSugg"}
       ..style.width = (minorSquareWidth.round()-2).toString().concat("px")
       ..style.height = (minorSquareHeight.round()-2).toString().concat("px")
       ..style.float = "left"
       ..style.border = "1px solid"
       ..innerHtml = (j+1).toString();
       ..onClick.listen(showOptionsSquare);

      optionsSquare.children.add(minorSquare);
      j++;
    }
```

If I try using @Pandian's way, it works, but I only get the value of the last element inside the loop. What I want is to somehow, track down the element clicked and get its value!

**EDIT 2**

Guys, just solved it!

I'll let the code here as a repo if someone needs this information:

```
void showOptionsSquare(Event e){
  window.location.hash = "#optionsPanel";
  mainDiv.style.opacity = (0.2).toString();

  DivElement clicked = e.target;
  window.alert(clicked.innerHtml);
}
```

[]'s

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670173/get-value-of-selected-select-element-in-dart

Comment: Wasn't exactly what i wanted, but it's always nice to have more knowledge about this kind of issue, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below... it will help you...

```
DivElement div;

void showValue(){
      window.alert(div.innerHTML); 
}

void main() { 
  div = query('#blah');
  div.on.click.add((Event e) => showValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! Isn't working exactly as i wanted, because i'm binding click events in elements created in a loop, so, it's getting only the last element created by the loop value, but you gave me a good direction, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Using your example code you could just write

```dart
print(e.target.innerHtml);
```

inside of your `showValue` function and it would work. Do you get an error or something? If you are worried about the warning you could add a cast to `Element` or `DivElement`:

```dart
print((e.target as Element).innerHtml);
```

Comment: What exactly does your exception say? Your other example works fine for me too. I'm using the bleeding edge version of the editor but I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: The stacktrace:
 
**Exception: NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'value'
Receiver: Instance of 'DivElement'
Arguments: []
Stack Trace: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1746:25)
#1      showOptionsSquare.showOptionsSquare (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/avaz/dart/sudoku_trial/web/out/sudoku_trial.dart:93:25)**

Comment: Ah, ok. So you tried accessing value instead of innerHtml. Value only works for input-Elements.

Comment: Omg, can't believe i let something like that pass lol Thanks a lot... If you don't mind, i'd like to hear your opinion... What solution you think is more "clean", mine or yours?

Comment: There isn't much of a difference. You are calling e.target.innerHtml and I'm doing that too. Do whatever you are more comfortable with ;). If you want to do more things with your DivElement I would go for your solution.